# Cloud architecture design

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-computing, network-design

I am designing a cloud architecture on AWS for a system processing large number of entities. I hope that this is the correct StackExchange for this question (SO did not seem appropriate to me - feel free to migrate the question).

**Problem description**

I have a large number (lets assume *n = 1 000 000* for this scenario) of entities in a database (objects accessible by their keys - basically a noSQL DB). I have an algorithm which is able to take two objects and produce a value indicating their similarity (lets say the computation takes approx. 10ms).

The system should be able to both compare an arbitrary entity to ALL the entities in my DB and also to identify all duplicities in my DB (that means a comparison of each entity against each other entity!).

**Design**

- DynamoDB (or similar noSQL storage for my entities)
- Processor - main service running on EC2 which is going to load all the entity keys and place requests for computations into a scalable queue (SQS) - assign workload for other workers
- Workload queue - queue with computation requests
- Workers - services deployed to ElasticBeanstalk connected to the workload queue. Workers connect to the database, fetch the entities to be compared and run the algorithm
- ResultsDB - either relational or non-relational DB with results from the workers

I put it on paper and did some basic estimations (with reasonable number of workers using multiple threads each) and figured out that it takes too much time to perform the duplicity identification - it is reasonably good for "one against all" comparison but trying to perform 1000000^2 operations is just too much.

I was thinking about using Hadoop with MapReduce but it seems that I would have to launch a new job for each "one against the others" comparison (and running million jobs does not sound very fast).

Therefore, I would be very glad for any suggestions how make my design better and overcome these pitfalls. Moreover, is the task (each vs each comparison) even doable without the need of running hundreds of powerful instances (price is also a limitation).

Comment: Why have you chosen noSQL?

Comment: Because the data are not relational in any way (though I could probably store it in SQL DB, just didnt make sense to me)

Comment: Wouldn't you only need to do the duplicates comparison once?  Why would you need to repeat it?

Comment: Technically yes... if I keep checking for duplicates when inserting new entity. But even the initial duplicate comparison takes too long

Comment: Could you please provide some details on your data / comparison algorithm? Cause if you really need to compare "all against all", you will have O(n^2) complexity. With 10ms for one operation, it needs about 57870 days to accomplish on one CPU. If data/algorithm allows you to avoid it, e.g., you could first sort your data using O(n*log(n)) algorithm (and remove duplicated during such sorting), and then do binary search to find duplicates for all new coming events. In this case you could drastically reduce number of operations needed.

Comment: There is one practical way out of the general problem you described: if you don't do each of the comparison, one-by-one, indendependently. If you can optimize the compare operation in such a way that performing multiple compare operations consumes less resources than performing those operations separately (eg by factoring some part of it), then you have the chance to avoid n*n*10ms. Apart from such a transformation of the original problem, there is no generic "magic", which could achieve the same result.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.. I myself did not implement the compare algorithm so I had the feeling that this cannot be achieved in an efficient way without changing how it works internally.

Comment: Yes. However, these changes should not be something extraordinary. E.g., MergeSort and binary search should do all for you, if applicable to your data.

Comment: This is likely way off base, but I had a similar problem with a very large heirarchy of files.  Generating an md5sum on the files and doing a sort|uniq -d on the table of sums was an efficient and fast way to identify the duplicates.  Perhaps you could generate a hash of the data and do the same in your db.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for 'duplicates', and your metric is euclidian, then you probably don't need to know the distances between far distant objects.  Googling for something like 'efficient knn' will likely get you on track.

Intuitive analogy: if you're looking for neighbours within 50km of someone in Greece, don't spend a lot of time calculating the distances to all the people in the US.  Those distances will never be important for finding neighbours.